# Want to know which insect it is? I often found it in washroom. Is it dangerous and how to control it

Tags: entomology

This insect found in the wash room.  Its so fast and disappears once someone enters the washroom.  Is it dangerous?  Whats name of this insect.  How to control this insect

[image]

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add your geographical location and the size range of this animal? Can you estimate the number of legs?

Answer (score 2):

That is a house centipede, *Scutigera coleoptrata* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scutigera_coleoptrata
They are harmless, unless you are a cockroach or termite. People find them unpleasant and creepy, because they run fast, but they are predators that prey on pests in your home. 
https://www.familyhandyman.com/pest-control/heres-why-you-should-never-kill-a-house-centipede/

Comment: They do seem to have a rather nasty bite. Maybe it is nice to add that to your answer?

Comment: No they don't. It may be possible that 1 encounter in a million ends up in a bite, when people are handling them, but I have never heard of it. People have an irrational fear of these completely harmless creatures, and the last thing you would need to say it that there is a minuscule chance that a huge one could bite if you put it in your hands and squeeze it.